# Validation for dependent create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Here are two models

Product and Variant

```
class Product.rb
 has_many :variants, dependent: :destroy
end

class Variant.rb
 belongs_to :product
end

Variant.create(product_id:rand(500..3000))
```

The above line creates a variant in the db even if product is not present with that particular id.
To handle this,
in before_create I could query and check if product is present.

Other than this *is there any in-built method or function that rails provides to handle such cases*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
class Variant.rb
  belongs_to :product
  validates :product, presence: true
end
```

According to the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence), this will ensure the `product` record actually exists.

BTW, it should be `belongs_to :product`, not `belongs_to :products`.

Comment: Thanks that worked.
belongs_to :products was a typo, correct that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like below in variant.rb

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :product
end
```

**In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default after [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937) change.**

In Rails 4.x world To add validation on belongs_to association, we need to add option required: true .

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, required: true
end
```

Comment: the rails version that I use is  5.0.1
if product_id is nil I get this error in variant.erros :product_id => ["can't be blank"]  but if I give some random number it is getting created.

Comment: You mean to say if product 233 is not present in database and you try to create variant with product id 233, it create the new variant ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant, that was my question.

Comment: @Surya That should not happen with Rails 5. Even if you give a random product_id which doesn't exist on your DB, it throws an error and does a rollback.

Comment: @Surya I never tried in `rails 5.0.1` . not sure its available in this version or not

Comment: @RaviTejaDandu no it doesnt, I guess you would have added product_id as foriegn key and hence it threw an DB error and not a rails error.
Rails doesn't detect the presence of product object.

Comment: @Surya I think you have to set `required:true` in **rails 5.0.1** . Please try setting the same and let me know if it helped.

Comment: You can go through the documentation here http://devdocs.io/rails~5.0/activerecord/associations/classmethods#method-i-belongs_to

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 by default the `reference` is required when you specify a `belongs_to` relation. You need to specify `optional: true` in case you do not want any compulsion on `reference` presence.

In Rails 4, you need to specify `required: true` to ensure the `reference` object is present and valid.

```
belongs_to :product, required: true
```

You can checkout the blogpost below:

https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

Hope this helped.